# JavaScript Arrays noob

Tags: javascript

So I have an array and when I run the code I want it to say "ERROR: You are banned" if any of those names are typed in. If not then I want it to say "Have a good time". I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please correct me!

```
var i = ["Michael", "Junior", "Chris"] {
  var names = function (names) {
      for(i = 0; i < i.length; i++) {
          if (i = names) {
              return("ERROR: You are banned!);
              }        
          else {
          return("Have a good time!");
          }
      }    
  }
};
```

Comment: You're missing this --> `"`...

Comment: also, assignment `=` ... test for equality `==` ... test for stricter equality `===` ... also, you are creating a function called `names` without running it, and your line 1 is totally wrong ... looking at this, you need to step back and learn (re-learn?) javascript syntax

Comment: hey dude, can you explain what you are doing there?

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong?

Comment: also `return` is not a function. You should not call return with parens.

Answer (score 0):

In your `return ("Error: You are banned!);` you are missing a closing quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

```
var checkName = function(name){
    var names = ["Michael", "Junior", "Chris"];
    if(names.indexOf(name) > -1){
         return "error";
    }else{
         return "have a good time";
    }
}
```

you'll  probably want to lowercase everything before checking it also.